# What is difference between System.Drawing.Image.FromFile() and just Image.FromFile()

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing.imaging

I'm new to programming.

I want to know in VB.NET what is difference between these two:

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()
```

and

```
Image.FromFile()
```

I used both on a picturebox, and both worked.
I just want to know what is difference and which is standard.

Comment: The first notation references the complete namespace, while the second is a shortcut and implies you added `using System.Drawing` somewhere on top of your class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a new WinForms VB.NET project using Visual Studio, you will find that the namespace `System.Drawing` is automatically added to the project references and an `Import System.Drawing` is already in place.

Try to right click on your project, listed in the Solution Explorer window, then select Properties and then click on the References tab.
You will see two lists. The first one contains the references to the assemblies automatically added to your project, the second list contains the Import statements implicitily written for you by the VS IDE

This means that you can call any method from the classes included in the System.Drawing namespace without fully qualifying them. This is also true for the other imported namespaces like System (For example, you don't need to write `System.Convert.ToInt32` but just `Convert.ToInt32`).

In this context doesn't matter if you type the fully qualified method name or just the abbreviated version. You can always write the fully qualified name.

Of course the shortcut provided importing the reference is very handy and will save a lot of time during coding.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is just the fully qualified `namespace`. If you have imported the `System.Drawing` namespace you can access the `Image.FromFile()` without calling the whole namespace.

Comment: I did not import System.Drawing namespace but Image.FromFile(string) is working. Should i import System.Drawing or can i use image.fromfile() in general without importing namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You're calling one with the full name space `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(string)` and the other `Image.FromFile(string)` without it. The second call assumes that you've included `using System.Drawing` in your class.

Comment: I did not import System.Drawing namespace but Image.FromFile(string) is working.
Should i import System.Drawing or can i use image.fromfile() in general without importing namespace.

Comment: Could it already be included as a reference in your project? In either case there should be no difference in the method calls you are making.